# Django: nested custom template tags

Tags: python, django, templates

I have written 2 custom template tags in Django.
The goal is to use one custom tag inside of another. Is it permitted?
The template for custom "outer" tag looks like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for type in types %}
         {% custom_internal_tag param1 %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Which after rendering results in

> Invalid block tag: 'custom_internal_tag', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'

Are nested custom tags allowed? What would be the cause of such an error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are definitely allowed, but that error can come up because your custom tag is not properly defined, located or loaded.

Make sure all your custom tags are located in your `app/templatetags` directory and are loaded properly, usually using the `@register` decorator.

*Reference:* https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters

Comment: Indeed, my template for outer tag didn't contain {% load internal_tag %} code.

Comment: In my case - when some custom tags include other custom tags say: `{% tag_from_lib1 %} {% tag_from_lib2 %} {% endtag_from_lib1 %}` - I had to first load `lib2`, and then `lib1`, i.e. I had to change `{% load lib2 lib1 %}` to `{% load lib2 %} {% load lib1 %}`. Otherwise the "invalid block tag" error kicked in.